# Powershell replace vs sed

Tags: windows, powershell, sed, parallel-processing

I need to convert a cygwin sed character search and replace operation to powershell and am getting very long processing times. Maybe I am doing something wrong, or maybe someone has a better way. I need to search and replace large files (>10GB) efficiently in a Windows 10 environment. Using split sed and cat I can achieve search replace on 10GB in less than 1 minute. Current Powershell operation is taking 45 seconds to process 100MB. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

```
$ time sed 's/a/Z/g' xaa > xaa.txt  
real    0m1.796s
$ Measure-Command {get-content xaa | % { $_ -replace 'a' , 'Z' } | out-file -encoding Ascii xaa.txt}
Seconds           : 45 

$ wc xaa
 Lines    Words   Chrs
 1000000  1000000 99000000 xaa

$ ls -lta xaa
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 ktst None 99000000 Jan 30 18:38 xaa

$ head -3 xaa
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ZZZZ
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ZZZZ
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ZZZZ

$ head -3 xaa.txt
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`Zbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ZZZZ
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`Zbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ZZZZ
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`Zbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ZZZZ
```

Comment: Yes, powershell is painfully slow. Sounds like you should just stick to the Windows port of `sed`.

Comment: PowerShell is a full .Net, capable first-class citizen. Meaning, it has access to all of .Net on the system. Have you looked at that approach before using a port?

Comment: Target environment is a corporate workstation, so I need a windows native solution. TextPad like is not really acceptable as file sizes increase. I was hoping there was a command line solution already developed that was being used by windows experts..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before jumping into conclusions (@SomethingDark) like "*powershell is painfully slow*", I recommend you to do some background reading on the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) and [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-server/administration/performance-tuning/powershell/script-authoring-considerations) as you not just comparing an external `sed` command against a [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) operator but also a *general* idiomatic way to *stream* each line of a file (using [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)) supporting complex serialized *objects* rather than flat text and a lot more features.

#### comparing apples to oranges

If you want to compare the performance of `sed` command against `-replace` operator, you should either compare this:

```
(Measure-Command { get-content ./Test.txt | % { $_ -replace 'a' , 'Z' } }).TotalMilliseconds
2648.3319

(Measure-Command { get-content ./Test.txt | % { $_ | sed 's/a/Z/g' } }).TotalMilliseconds   
305261.8114
```

or do something like this:

```
(Measure-Command { sed 's/a/Z/g' ./Test.txt }).TotalMilliseconds
233.4965

(Measure-Command {
    $path = Join-Path (Get-Location) 'Test.txt'
    $stream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($path)
    while ($line = $stream.ReadLine()) { $Line -replace 'a' , 'Z' }
    $stream.Dispose()
}).TotalMilliseconds
368.3232
```

Comment: This is interesting and much more reasonable timings, thanks! How would this scale to the ~10GB range? Would there be any memory constraints? Could multiple worker processes be launched simultaneously then result set concatenated?

Comment: If you directly append the result of each replacement to the output file, there shouldn't be any memory constraints.